# Stansted Express. Do I actually need to print my e-ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, stn

I have booked an advance ticket for the Stansted Express. I opted to have the ticket sent by email (e-ticket) rather than by SMS to my phone (m-ticket).

The info on the [Stansted Express site](https://www.stanstedexpress.com/contact-us/faqs) says that I need to print the ticket before I travel.

Do I really need to print it out, or can I just show the ticket (it's a PDF which contains barcodes for scanning) on my phone?

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.

Comment: It looks like the answer might have changed with the app for the line.

Answer (score 12):

As you state, the FAQ answers your question:

> This ticket needs to be printed at home and presented to the Stansted Express station or onboard staff to be scanned as a valid ticket for travel.

In other words, if you present your phone with the ticket on, the inspector may tell you that your ticket is not valid, and you will have to pay for a full price fare on the train. I have heard of this actually occurring.

It is, of course, a non-sensical policy, but unless you comply, you are risking a fine.

Comment: A way out may be to have it send again but now to your phone, in the M-ticket format.

Comment: In my experience of buying train tickets, the 'delivery mode' you select is fixed. If you select e-ticket, you can't change to a mobile ticket and vice versa.

Comment: I'm speaking specifically about mobile tickets in the UK. Once you have selected your delivery option (post, collect at station, print at home, mobile ticket), it is fixed and impossible to change.

Answer (score 8):

No need to print it, since you can retroactively import the ticket into the Stansted Express mobile app.

You only need the ticket reference number and the email address you used when purchasing the ticket. Install the app, login or create an account, select `Account > Import Ticket`, enter the information and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

No need to print ticket. I am literally on Stansted Express right now and I just have the PDF e-ticket downloaded on my phone. No need to print or download  app.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could back it up with a link to FAQ or policy, thereby proving that your experience was typical rather than a fluke/at the whim of the conductor.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas although to be fair even if the FAQ says one thing sadly it does not mean the guard will necessarily follow it. Would be interesting to know if the OP got through the station barriers OK too.